# Embed an swf video format that has interactive features into an HTML

Tags: html, embed, flash

I'm trying to embed an swf video format that has interactive features into an HTML and find difficulty in that. So, I would highly appreciate if you could guide me on the best best way to do that without affecting the interactive features of the swf video.

Kindest Regards
Mahmoud

Comment: can you show your codde

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Code for this:

```
<object width="400" height="50" data="bookmark.swf"></object>
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you so much for being so helpful. I wonder if you could send me the steps for using this code to upload the swf on a blogger. Bearing in mind that the swf video is a published output of a trial version of Adobe Captivate 8. And what's the best free host website that enables me do so easily?

Comment: Hi, If you want this to be available as a page or post, you can upload the swf file to dropbox and then use code like this `<object width="400" height="50" data="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/102527083/Testing.swf"></object>`.

Comment: You can refer to [Embed and Upload SWF in Google Blogger POST](http://embed-swf-in-blogger.blogspot.sg/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I really appreciate your valuable information.